# Push Notifications in iOS 8 ( Parse )

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, ios8

After installing iOS 8 on my iDevice it does not receive push notifications from Parse anymore. I tried to send notifications from Parse, it says that sent successful, but nothing happens on device. Console says that device registered successfully to receive notifications. 
I am using the following code to setup notifications.

```
//-- Set Notification
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: I am using parse & iOS8, i receive notifications without issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried out the code you did but switched [UIApplication sharedApplication] with just application and it worked fine on my iOS8 device.

```
//-- Set Notification
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{ [application registerUserNotificationSettings:
   [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                  (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | 
                   UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | 
                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | 
      UIUserNotificationTypeSound | 
      UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it working with the code above, and the following:

1. Downloaded the uploaded parse framework from parse.com.
2. Clean the project in Xcode and rebuild.

Before I downloaded the updated framework, my devices did not register their deviceTokens at parse.com in the installation table, and iOs 8 devices did not receive pushes